# Integral of $e^{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

What is the integral of $e^{x^2}$?
Although I am only a beginner in calculus, all I could understand from a Google search was this resembles a error function (no minus behind the x) and these don't have a simple solution.
On the list of integrals of exponential functions on wikipedia,the integral is given, but I cannot understand the result and no further reference or proof is given.

Comment: In beginner calculus, we in general use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and solve an integral of a function f by finding a primitive of that function (i.e., a function F such that F'=f). Not always we can find "nice" primitives and this is the case for this one.

Comment: There are no expressions for $\int e^{x^2} dx$ or $\int e^{-x^2} dx$ in terms of elementary functions. The second of these two integrals is related to the error function, which you can find written up in many places.

Comment: What about the one on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions) under other intergrals(in the page.)?

Comment: What is usually surprising to most calculus students is that despite all those mental puzzles you get in class and derivatives which almost always reduce to something nice integrals don't usually reduce to a ``nice answer."    Often we are required to use the area definition or more sophisticated methods to estimate them.